# Java Ant: classpath hierachy

Tags: java, ant

I have several class files like such hierarchy directories:

```
classes
└── com
    ├── www
    │   ├── ant
    │   │   └── TAPJUnitResultFormatter.class
    │   ├── taglib
    │   │   └── IncludeTag.class
    │   ├── tomcat
    │   ├── util
```

How could I include them in classpath? I tried to include them one by one, but didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You might find this helpful](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html)

Quoted:

> When classes are stored in a directory (folder), like /java/MyClasses/utility/myapp, then the class path
>   entry points to the directory that contains the first element of the
>   package name. (in this case, /java/MyClasses, since the package name
>   is utility.myapp.)
>
> But when classes are stored in an archive file (a .zip or .jar file)
>   the class path entry is the path to and including the .zip or .jar
>   file. For example, to use a class library that is in a .jar file, the
>   command would look something like this:
>
> % java -classpath /java/MyClasses/myclasses.jar utility.myapp.Cool

So basically, point it to the root directory that all your classes exist under. Your "MyClasses" folder is probably named "bin".

Comment: It makes sense, then how to set up the name at '<include name="*.class"/>' If I only include the top path.

Comment: No need, you'll just have a path with only one folder element.

Comment: I set like this <fileset dir="/home/user/tasks/myproject/classes">
    </fileset>. And 'classes' is the top directory above 'com', but looks still awkward. It didn't work. It still complained couldn't resolve 'import com.www.util.*;'It must be some basic thing I forgot.

Comment: Ha, looks better this time. I should use <pathelement location="/home/user/tasks/myproject/classes"/>. Thanks.